# Validating a form without javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation

Is it possible to validate a form without Javascript? Rest of my website is written in c# and asp.net and the server hosting my website doesn't allow Javascript. Is there any other ways to validate a form without this? Thanks!

```
function validateForm()
{
var x=document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value;
var atpos=x.indexOf("@");
var dotpos=x.lastIndexOf(".");
if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length)
  {
   alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
   return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Well i know, that's not an answer. But if hoster does not allow javascript... run away from him

Comment: Why would the server care if you run JavaScript on remote unrelated machines?

Comment: If it "doesn't allow javascript" you can't run half of your C# codes because even they are using javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can let the browser validate it partially.

To do this, you can use the `pattern` attribute, `required`, etc.

[Further Reading](http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-form-validation/).

Answer (score 0):

For built in email validation set up input type to email:

```
   <input type="email" name="email">
```

If it's required add another attribute:

```
   <input type="email" name="email" required>
```

But remember, that it's only client side validation and supported by not [all browsers](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_form_input_types.asp), so you must check input on server as well